# multiple thread signal handling

Tags: c, linux

I have above code for debugging what happens when we do signal masking for different threads. What i see in this code is that the first thread being masked for USR2 gets the whole process terminated.

It will be great if some on help me why this happens and how can we handle different signals in different threads using pthread_sigmask.

I tried to create a thread from main function with some signal masks and then created a new thread from the current thread with removing some signal masks. Even i tried adding extra signal mask for new thread still the program terminates.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Simple error handling functions */

#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static void *
sig_thread_1(void *arg)
{
    sigset_t *set = arg;
    int s, sig;
printf("%p created\n",pthread_self() );
        printf("after new set %s SIGUSR1\n",sigismember(set,SIGUSR1)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after new set %s SIGUSR2\n",sigismember(set,SIGUSR2)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after new set %s SIGRTMIN\n",sigismember(set,SIGRTMIN)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after new set %s SIGQUIT\n",sigismember(set,SIGQUIT)==0?"is not":"is" );

    for (;;) {
        s = sigwait(set, &sig);
        if (s != 0)
            handle_error_en(s, "sigwait");
        printf("Signal handling %lu thread got signal %d\n",pthread_self(), sig);
    }
}

static void *
sig_thread(void *arg)
{
    sigset_t *set = arg;
    int s, sig;
        sigset_t set1=*set;
        pthread_t thread1;
    //  sigemptyset(&set1);
        sigdelset(&set1, SIGQUIT);
        sigdelset(&set1, SIGUSR1);
        printf("%p created\n",pthread_self() );
                printf("after old set %s SIGUSR1\n",sigismember(set,SIGUSR1)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after old set %s SIGUSR2\n",sigismember(set,SIGUSR2)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after old set %s SIGRTMIN\n",sigismember(set,SIGRTMIN)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after old set %s SIGQUIT\n",sigismember(set,SIGQUIT)==0?"is not":"is" );
        s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set1, NULL);
        if (s != 0)
            handle_error_en(s, "pthread_sigmask");

        s = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &sig_thread_1, (void *) &set1);
        if (s != 0)
            handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create fail");


        printf("after old set1 %s SIGUSR1\n",sigismember(&set1,SIGUSR1)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after old set1 %s SIGUSR2\n",sigismember(&set1,SIGUSR2)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after old set1 %s SIGRTMIN\n",sigismember(&set1,SIGRTMIN)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after old set1 %s SIGQUIT\n",sigismember(&set1,SIGQUIT)==0?"is not":"is" );
    //  return;
    for (;;) {
                printf("after old set %s SIGUSR1\n",sigismember(set,SIGUSR1)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after old set %s SIGUSR2\n",sigismember(set,SIGUSR2)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after old set %s SIGRTMIN\n",sigismember(set,SIGRTMIN)==0?"is not":"is" );
        printf("after old set %s SIGQUIT\n",sigismember(set,SIGQUIT)==0?"is not":"is" );
        s = sigwait(set, &sig);
        if (s != 0)
            handle_error_en(s, "sigwait");
        printf("Signal handling %lu thread got signal %d\n",pthread_self(), sig);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_t thread1;
    sigset_t set;
    int s;

   /* Block SIGQUIT and SIGUSR1; other threads created by main()
       will inherit a copy of the signal mask. */

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR2);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGRTMIN);
    s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_sigmask");
    s = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &sig_thread, (void *) &set);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create fail");

   /* Main thread carries on to create other threads and/or do
       other work */

   pause();            /* Dummy pause so we can test program */
}
```